# Python: merge n-dictionaries depending on several values + sum

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, conditional-statements

Let´s say I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'amount': 42140.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 385, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
{'amount': 43926.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 641}, 
{'amount': 3800.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476},
{'amount': 46330.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
{'amount': 67357.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 323},
{'amount': 26441.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476} ... ]
```

I would like to merge the dictionaries together so that the key "amount" would be a sum of all `amounts` from dictionaries where `account_id_credit` and `account_id_debit` are the same but only if `type` of those is `expense`. Other `types` should stay as they are.

What´s the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't see how you could merge the dicts together.  `amount` is a numeric field so you could just add those values up, but what about the other fields?  There are at least three different values for `account_id_debit`.  How are you going to pick just one of those to use in the merged dict?

Comment: Well, that´s precisely it - adding values up for amount in a single dict for all dicts where account_id_debit and account_id_credit are the same. Actualy the "name" could be whatever, the value from the first dict for instance. Kind of deduplicating with aggregation if you get me.

Comment: did you try to do it yourself?

Comment: Looks like a case for `pandas.DataFrame` and some `groupby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate dictionaries by those keys and sum the `amount` variable where needed.

```
dicts = [{'amount': 42140.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 385, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
         {'amount': 43926.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 641}, 
         {'amount': 3800.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476},
         {'amount': 46330.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
         {'amount': 67357.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 323},
         {'amount': 26441.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}]


def aggregate(dicts, keys):
    def worker(aggr, dic):
        key_vals = tuple(dic[key] for key in keys)
        aggr.setdefault(key_vals, {key: [] for key in dic.iterkeys()})
        for key, value in dic.iteritems():
            aggr[key_vals][key].append(value)
        return aggr

    assert len(set(tuple(dic.iterkeys()) for dic in dicts)) == 1
    return reduce(worker, dicts, {})


keys = ("account_id_credit", "type", "account_id_debit")
aggr_expense = [dic for keys, dic in aggregate(dicts, keys).iteritems() if keys[1] == u"expense"]
merged_expense = [{key: sum(value) if key == "amount" else value[0] for key, value in dic.iteritems()}
                  for dic in aggr_expense]
result = merged_expense + filter(lambda dic: dic["type"] != u"expense", dicts)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 476, 'amount': 76571.0, 'type': u'expense', 'name': 'Payment'},
 {'account_id_credit': 385, 'account_id_debit': 476, 'amount': 42140.0, 'type': u'expense', 'name': 'Payment'},
 {'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 641, 'amount': 43926.0, 'type': u'payable', 'name': 'Payment'}, 
 {'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 323, 'amount': 67357.0, 'type': u'payable', 'name': 'Payment'}]
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to create an intermediate dictionary, keyed by a tuple of `(account_id_credit, account_id_debit)` with a running total of the amount values, and then to build you aggregated dictionary list from that:

```
ld = [{'amount': 42140.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 385, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
{'amount': 43926.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 641}, 
{'amount': 3800.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476},
{'amount': 46330.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476}, 
{'amount': 67357.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'payable', 'account_id_debit': 323},
{'amount': 26441.0, 'name': 'Payment', 'account_id_credit': 695, 'type': u'expense', 'account_id_debit': 476} ]


d2 = {}
for d in ld:
    if d['type'] != 'expense':
        continue
    k = (d['account_id_credit'], d['account_id_debit'])
    try:
        d2[k] += d['amount']
    except KeyError:
        d2[k] = d['amount']

ld2 = []
for d in ld:
    if d['type'] != 'expense':
        ld2.append(d)
        continue
    k = (d['account_id_credit'], d['account_id_debit'])
    try:
        d['amount'] = d2[k]
        # We're done with this amount sum: remove it from the intermediate dict
        del d2[k]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    ld2.append(d)
print ld2

[{'account_id_credit': 385, 'account_id_debit': 476, 'amount': 42140.0, 'type': u'expense', 'name': 'Payment'},
 {'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 641, 'amount': 43926.0, 'type': u'payable', 'name': 'Payment'},
 {'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 476, 'amount': 76571.0, 'type': u'expense', 'name': 'Payment'},
 {'account_id_credit': 695, 'account_id_debit': 323, 'amount': 67357.0, 'type': u'payable', 'name': 'Payment'}]
```

Comment: You can replace that `try`/`except` block in the beginning with a `dict.setdefault` call, i.e. `d2.setdefault(k, 0); d2[k] += d["amount"]`. It will shave off a couple of lines.